# ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE to opening my localhost in Chrome Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, gruntjs, browser-sync

I´m using the task BrowserSync of Grunt, this task launch my local project to the url "localhost:3000".

[image]

This works fine. But when I use the External url (http://192.168.1.129:3000) in my smartphone, I get the following error of my browser Chrome in Android:

```
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

I don't understand this problem. You can see here my Gruntfile.js:

```
//Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({

    //Watch task config
    watch: {

    },
    //BrowserSync
    browserSync: {
      default_options: {
        bsFiles: {
          src: [
            "css/*.css",
            "js/*.js",
            "*.html"
          ]
        },
        options: {
          watchTask: true,
          proxy: "tutorialmaterialize.dev"
          }
        }
      }

    });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

 //Default task
 grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync', 'watch']);
};
```

how can i fix this?, thanks you very much.

Comment: This is a network issue. Both your phone and your computer on the same LAN? Also firewall could be blocking external access from the phone, you should allow it

Comment: My Mac OS X Firewall is disabled, and my phone and computer are connect to my Wi-Fi Router.

Answer (score 1):

your IP starts with 192.168 which means this is a private network.

Only devices on the private network can access it.

Your phone will need to be on the same network.

You can check this by checking the first 3 digits of your phone's IP - the first 3 digits must be the same - if they begin 192.168.1.NUMBER then its on the same network. If not then its on a different network and you need to get them on the same network.

If they are already on the same network then ensure that port 3000 is open on the firewall, both the router firewall AND the firewall running on the machine you are accessing.

Comment: OP already mentioned in the comment that his phone is connected to the same network.

Answer (score 0):

if your port of the server is 3000
and chick for your ip in cmd by this ...: ipconfig 
ip4 : 192.168.11 than add it in mobile and on the desktop way view 
example

on your mobile chrome 
http://192.168.1.11:3000/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using Chrome on my Ubuntu 18.04; I solved by installing a firewall manager (Firewall Configuration) and freeing the 8080 port. On your case would be port 3000 but the process is the same.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuLu0.jpg

Answer (score -1):

For some router after both my mobile device and my PC are all the same network and also off all firewall for testing.It not work at all.
Finally I have had solved it by pinging test from the PC side first. After that my android phone can be access to my local web server.
I think that the real issue may came from WIFI access point device configuration.